# сборка XSD схем для реализованного WCF сервиса

Tags: .net, xml, wcf, xsd

Подскажите пожалуйста, имеется готовый WCF сервис, который принимает данные (модель запроса), далее обрабатывает и возвращает ответ. Сторона которая будет использовать данный сервис, просит предоставить им XSD схемы данного сервиса, для настроек со своей стороны, как правильнее всего собрать схемы, что нужно учесть? Содержит ли wsdl наименования типов которые нужны для успешной реализации клиента на вызывающей стороне? В общем хотелось бы понять как собрать схемы сервиса чтобы вызывающая сторона без проблем смогла провести настройки со своей стороны по предоставленным мною файлам. Большое всем спасибо, могу предоставить все что необходимо для полноты картины.

Comment: WSDL достаточно, больше ничего не надо.

Comment: Спасибо Александр, я тоже считал что достаточно wsdl, но вызывающая сервис сторона требуют XSD схемы, поэтому тут нужно их предоставить, других вариантов нет.

Comment: Хм. Посмотрите это: [Exporting Schemas from Classes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/exporting-schemas-from-classes)

Comment: Схема XSD может быть создана на основе XML. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте свой вопрос и добавьте XML.